# selenium webdriver_Is there any other way to find out the count of webelements present in a webpage without using "findElements()" method?

Tags: selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

Is there any other way to find out the count of webelements present in a webpage without using "findElements()" method?

This Question is asked in Interview. So I would like to know whether it is possible to get the count of Webelements without using findElements().

Answer (score 1):

Update to @mate and @custom answer,

using xpath, to extract the number.

```
driver.executeScript(() => $x('count(//div)'));
```

if there is 25 div elements, will return 25 as a number.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

1. Go to DevTools
2. Enter `$x('//*')` to console
3. You will get the number of **HTML** elements

Answer (score 0):

You could use `WebDriver.prototype.executeScript` which lets you execute some JavaScript code. That code can either be a function or a string:

```
driver.executeScript(() => document.querySelectorAll('*').length);
```

PS: I'm using the JS flavour of `selenium-webdriver`.